# How to override abstract's method with it's body template in dart?

Tags: oop, flutter, dart, overriding, abstract-class

I want something like this:

```
abstract class A {

  void someMethod(dataStates) {
    switch (dataStates) {
      case DataStates.loading:
        stackIndex = 0;
        break;
      case DataStates.failed:
        stackIndex = 1;
        break;
      case DataStates.completed:
        stackIndex = 2;
        break;
    } // switch
  } // someMethod

} // class A


class B implements A {

  @override
  void someMethod(dataStates) {
    switch (dataStates) {
      case DataStates.loading:
        stackIndex = 0;
        break;
      case DataStates.failed:
        stackIndex = 1;
        break;
      case DataStates.completed:
        stackIndex = 2;
        break;
    } // switch
  } // someMethod

} // class B
```

But when I override someMethod() in class B, I get a method with empty body like this:

```
  @override
  void someMethod(dataStates) {
    // TODO: implement someMethod
  }
```

How can I have a default(template) method body when overriding?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Which I understood, you just want a pre written template on override? Right?

Comment: @ShahzadAkram Exactly!

Comment: That's not possible if you just want to execute same code again you can just use `super.someMethod(dataStates);` as mentioned in the answers below. But which you are expecting might be possible with any third party plugin but it doesn't seem to be possible to be a part of dart SDK by default.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a code generator instead. May I suggest Freezed, which has a `when` function?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
@override
  void someMethod(dataStates) {
    super.someMethod(dataSates);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class B extends A { // extends not implements
  @override
  void someMethod(dataStates) {
    super.someMethod(dataStates);

    // Do what you want to do 
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to call method, I just want to have that template in overriding!

Comment: I want my method have a template code, when I override it

Comment: You want those `switch` statements to get automatically copied when you override, sorry this isn't possible, you need to manually do that.